# Django: access list of models belong of admin from admin console

Tags: python, django

I am sure this question has been asked before but I have not found anything regarding admin console.

The database relationship is as follows: Host can have multiple students but a student has only one host (one-to-many or many-to-one depends on how we look at the problem). Below is my model setup:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Student(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey("Host", blank=True, null=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    major = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    interests = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    attendance = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'student'

class Host(models.Model):
    host_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    max_guests = models.IntegerField(default=5, blank=True, null=True)
    preference = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'person'
```

I can access host of a student by using `.host` (e.g. `Student.objects.first().host`) and also from a dropdown in django admin console. I can also access a list of students of a particular host like this:

```
list_of_students_of_first_host = Student.objects.filter(host_id=Host.objects.first().host_id)
```

But I cannot see from admin console list of students of a particular host. How to accomplish this if it is even possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i'm not sure, but try to add a function life `def students(self):    return self.students_set.all()` and in admin.py add in the var list_diplay = ('students')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a **django admin inline** will let you display all the Students associated with a Host in the Host's admin page

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline

Comment: can you please explain further?